# Seagate 1 TB External drive encrypted with Bitlocker in error

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have encrypted my seagate 1TB drive with Bitlocker in error.  I have not put any files on the drive and would like to return it to its pre encrypted state.  I dont know how to format the drive and am looking for help.

Comment: Just turn off bitlocker and it will decrypt.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to format it like you usually do, the encryption just stops you from reading it. If in windows, go to computer and right click the drive. You should have an option to format the drive there. You can pick NTFS if you want it just for windows or FAT32 if you want to use it for multiple operating systems. Good luck!