# After Reformatting my seagte external 1TB drive it is now write protected

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have just reformatted my external Seagate 1 TB drive.  It will not allow me to copy anything on to the drive. A message comes up to say I need to remove write protection.  How do I do this?

Comment: Have you checked Disk Manager? (Assuming based on [your previous question](http://superuser.com/q/628080/53590) that you're running Windows.) Does it say anything relevant?

Answer (score 0):

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> (My Computer)
- Right click on the partition and select *properties*
- Go to the *security* tab
- Here you can change the permissions for any users
- Click on *Edit* on any selected user to change permission

The easy way would be to add *All Users* and grant full permission.

If you want these permission to persist in all sub-directories, then  go to:

- *Advanced >   -  Change Permissions*
- select the user which permissions you want to use as top level
- Check the *Replace alle permissions...* checkbox